# Best controls for nesting items

Tags: forms, selection

I am trying to develop a page editing backend, and one of my problems is about how to let the user choose where to nest the page he/she is editing. My boss came up with this solution:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7hAGB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I don't find it really intuitive, though I can't come with a better option that is easier to understand and to use. He plans that each section select would have an input next to it to create a new section a part. Sections are actually pages themselves, so there is no need to create them (in fact, if you create them "on the fly", there might be problmes)

Other options are:

**Use just a select with all the subsectioning inside the item list:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWfDXO.png)</sup>

**Use a "directory-like" metaphor, with folders, double click and so, to get to the desired section:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg2vIk.png)</sup>

This option should be accessible from the page edition, so I cannot use a large amount of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you want to create a navigation tree structure like in most OS + it would be easy to create a new page and to edit an old one.

The mockup shows: 1) Simple navigation tree, that allows you to edit any page that you want. 2) When you create a new page you can select from drop down where the page would go.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSRQlv.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This mockup is based on Wordpress

Comment: Despite yours is a good one, we finally did like my boss said without the new buttons. The last dropdown always shows something like "Add page here". If you choose another page, then a new dropdown is shown below with that option. Anyway, I still agree with you.